# Create a MultiIndex dataframe from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sktime

I have a dataframe which is formatted like in the picture below, the numbers ranging from 0 to 874.
[Extract of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep4xz.png)
I am trying to get a multiindex dataframe from it with the first element of the tuple as the "super" index and the second one as the "lower" index.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To use a simple example: if you have the DataFrame:

```
   (x, 1)  (y, 2)
0       1       4
1       2       5
2       3       6
```

the use

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

to produce the DataFrame

```
   x  y
   1  2
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```